# Settimeout not returning instantly

Tags: javascript, callback, settimeout

I was practicing with callback functions and this question is one I can't seem to figure out.

```
function foo () {    
  var data = 10;    
  bar(function (players) {
    data = players;
  });    
  return data;
}

function bar (callback) {
  setTimeout(callback, 0);
}

var result = foo();
```

I expected result to be undefined since `data = players` and there is nothing passed in as players. Since the setTimeout function uses `0` as the delay, shouldn't it run first, and then return data? I looked at the MDN page and there seems to be information on throttling for nested timeouts to `>=4ms`. Does this also apply in this case?

Comment: setTimeout is asynchronous call

Answer (score 1):

> Since the setTimeout function uses 0 as the delay, shouldn't it run first, and then return data?

No, even with a delay of `0`, the callback passed to `setTimeout` is scheduled to run in the [next tick of the event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop).

In other words, the callback is guaranteed to be executed *after* the current execution ran to completion.

Comment: "If there is no other message in the queue, the message is processed right away; however, if there are messages, the setTimeout message will have to wait for other messages to be processed." Since setTimeout is getting delayed, I'm guessing the "message" already in queue is the function call?

Comment: Not necessarily. But the queue is only looked at *after* the current code terminated. I.e. only after `var result = foo();` was executed.